# I'm trying to backreference using the sed command

Tags: shell

I am relatively new to shell scripting and sed. I need to substitute a pattern, globably, but I also need to remember (or save) part of the pattern and use it later in the same substitute command. The saved pattern will be variable, so I need to use a wild card. For example,

```
input message=trt:GetAudioSourcesRequest/>
```

and I want to end up with something like

```
input message=trt:GetAudioSourcesRequest PAUL/GetAudioSourcesRequest/>
```

but the function string `GetAudioSourcesRequest` will change (in length also) throughout the file, so I need a wild card, e.g.,

```
sed -i "s/input message=trt:<wild card in here>/>/input message=trt:<print wild card> PAUL/<print wild card>/>
```

I have managed to get the following command to nearly do what I want but it is too rigid. It only stores a 4 syllable pattern so if I have a function name such as `GetProfileRequest`, this doesn't work

```
echo "input message=\"trt:GetAudioSourcesRequest\"/>" | sed 's/input message=\"trt:\([A-Z][a-z]*\)\([A-Z][a-z]*\)\([A-Z][a-z]*\)\([A-Z][a-z]*\).*/input message=\"trt:\1\2\3\4\ PAUL\/\1\2\3\4"\/\>/g'
```

This outputs

```
input message="trt:GetAudioSourcesRequest PAUL/GetAudioSourcesRequest"/>
```

Which is ok, but when I use `GetProfileRequest` this doesn't work.

I have come across `\W` and `[^[:alnum:]]` or `[[:alnum:]]` but I don't how to use them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's|\(input message=trt:\)\([^/]*\)|\1\2 PAUL/\2|'
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. My full command,

echo "input message=\"trt:GetAudioSourcesRequest\"/>" | sed 's|\(input message=trt:\)\([^/]*\)|\1\2 PAUL/\2|'

the output

input message="trt:GetAudioSourcesRequest"/>

I don't think its executing the sed

Comment: Oh, I found my problem. I was missing a double quotes.

Thanks